# how to read the output of csv file and print the output in php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file using PHP. I want to use a while statement for each line, and would like to assign a variable for each column. The reason I am assigning variables for each column is so that I can use those variables within a sql query.

```
$csv = fopen('sample2.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($csv,1024)) {
    //Not sure what to do here
}
fclose($csv) or die("can't close file");
```

I understand how to open the file and read the overall line, but not how to control the individual columns.

Updated Code

```
<?php
    $csv = fopen('sample.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($csv,1024)) {
        list($column1, $column2, $column3) = $csv_line;
        echo 'Column 1: '.$column1.'<br />';
        echo 'Column 2: '.$column2.'<br />';
        echo 'Column 1: '.$column1.'<br />';
        echo 'Column 3: '.$column3.'<br />';
    }
    fclose($csv) or die("can't close file");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgetcsv` returns an array with each field in it. You can use the `list` function to get all columns in that array:

```
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($csv,1024)) {
    list($column1, $column2, $column3) = $csv_line;
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, however it only displays the first line..
See updated code above

Comment: I can only guess it has something to do with the hint #2 on this page: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I was able to get it to work properly, for some reason my csv didn't upload properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `print_r($csv_line)`, you will see that you're getting an array back, split by each field for you.

Answer (score 0):

$csv = fopen('sample2.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($csv,1024)) {
    $column0 = $csv_line[0];
    $column2 = $csv_line[0];
    $column3 = $csv_line[0];
    $column4 = $csv_line[0];
    $column = $csv_line[];

}
fclose($csv) or die("can't close file");

Answer (score 0):

you can use the csv reader class and simple parse you csv file data in to array format.

http://www.mbyte.in/csv-reader/

```html
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "csv_reader.php";
$csvObject=new Mbyte_Csv();
$file='seed.csv';
$data=$csvObject->getData($file);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```